# Google Directory API - Watch notifcations with far expiration

Tags: google-admin-sdk, google-apps-marketplace

The Directory API supports watching resources for changes, as documented here:
https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/directory/v1/guides/push

You can optionally set an expiration when you request a channel, and also a ttl (which is basically the same thing). But - neither of these make a difference, they are ignored.

Is this a bug in Google's API, or is there a workaround??

Here's an example request body:

```
{  
   "address":"https://www.example.com",
   "expiration":1477664588000,
   "id":"**my-id**",
   "params":{  
      "ttl":"86400"
   },
   "token":"SomeTokenHEre",
   "type":"web_hook"
}
```

Here I'm setting the expiration to 24 hours (unix timestamp in milliseconds), and ALSO setting the ttl to 24 hours (expressed as seconds). The response:

```
{
 "kind": "api#channel",
 "id": "*My-id*",
 "resourceId": "....",
 "resourceUri": "https://www.googleapis.com/admin/directory/v1/users?customer=my_customer&projection=basic&viewType=admin_view&alt=json",
 "token": "SomeTokenHere",
 "expiration": "1477600105000"
}
```

And that expiration is in 6 hours time. Always.

Comment: Can you add the request that you are using for this in your question? Also, try to use this [Try it](https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/directory/v1/reference/users/watch#try-it) part and check if the behavior of the results is the same.

Comment: Ta. The "try it" doesn't work - because in order to set a notification channel up, you need to register your web_hook endpoints with the Google API manager console. The try it stuff tries to execute as your google user (rather than the service account), so always rejects your web_hook endpoint.

Comment: The original point about the expiration coming back with an error was my fault - I was passing in an expiration in seconds, not milliseconds. I've updated the question now - looks like a bug in google's API?

Answer (score 1):

I am running into the same issue, and right now I think the problem is that you can only set a max of 6 hours for a channel and will have to "refresh"/recreate them every 6 hours.

I have just confirmed that you can set them for less via the request body method with the ttl param, so that is the valid way of doing it.

e.g. for 5 minutes

`{

   "address":"https://www.example.com",
   "expiration":1477664588000,
   "id":"**my-id**",
   "params":{

      "ttl":"300"
   },
   "token":"SomeTokenHEre",
   "type":"web_hook"
}`

But anything larger than that and it defaults it to 6 hours.  I can't find this mentioned anywhere or in the documentation, so I am not 100% sure, so if anyone else can confirm or if we can get official words from google devs it would be great.

Answer (score 0):

In the response from google
the expiration is in Unix(ms) epoch time which converted upon gives relative to 2 days which means channel is valid for 2 days
You can optionally set expiry limit though